# find 1's in the row

Tags: python, arrays, list, find

I have a task to do:

```
a = [0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]
```

I have the list - `a` - randomly generated each time the program runs.

Task 1: find the longest 1-row (here it is `[1,1,1,1]`) and output its starting index number.

Task 2: find `1,1` in `a`; how many times it occurs? `1,1,1` doesn't count, only exact matches are taken into account.

```py
a = [1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]

counter = 1

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 1:
        a[i] = counter
        counter += 1

print(a)

b = []
one_rows = []

for i in a:
    if i > 0:
        one_rows.append(i)
    if i == 0:
        b.append([one_rows])
        one_rows.clear()
print(b)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/354577) (TL;DR: It's never okay.)

Comment: "This if what i've wrote so far"—great! So what's wrong with this code? Is it giving an error message? What does it say? Is it just not doing what you want? Can you provide an example of what you expect, vs. what is happening instead? Please read [ask].

Comment: what do you mean by: 'and name its starting index number.' You want index where this row starts?

Comment: Does the first task allow duplicates? Such as ```[1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]```.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question right, you can use can use `itertools.groupby` to group the list and count the number of `1`s:

```py
a = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

max_len, double_ones, max_idx = float("-inf"), 0, 0
for v, g in groupby(enumerate(a), lambda k: k[1]):
    if v == 1:
        idxs = [i for i, _ in g]
        double_ones += len(idxs) == 2
        if len(idxs) > max_len:
            max_len = len(idxs)
            max_idx = idxs[0]

print("Longest 1-row:", max_len, "Index:", max_idx)
print("How many 1,1:", double_ones)
```

Prints:

```
Longest 1-row: 4 Index: 6
How many 1,1: 0
```